# How to add an array together without using array_sum

Tags: php

I'm tryng to learn PHP and I'm trying to do it by doing things the long way round.
So I came across array_sum() and I was wondering if there is a way to calculate an array without using it.

for example

```
$my_array = array(10, 80, 30);
```

I've only got as far as this and I'm stumped. I have looked on google but I haven't found anything.

```
$implode = implode(",", $my_array );

$explode = explode(",", $implode);

foreach($explode as $test)
{


 }
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you want to do this?

Comment: `$my_array` would be the same as `$explode`. Can you tell us what are you trying to do?

Comment: just so that I learn and understand

Comment: Whenever a native function is there, use it. Because it is optimized. Don't invent the wheel, again.

Answer (score 2):

I will always go for native functions as they are optimized as well as tested.[so basically i want to say that use `array_sum()`],

Apart from above, below is `foreach()` process to sum all values of a single-dimensional array[just for knowledge sake]

```
<?php


$result = 0; //create a variable with 0 value
foreach($explode as $test)
{
  $result += $test; //add array value to the newly created value

}

echo $result; //print final sum of all array values
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/0qMJu

Note:- please read @Markus Zeller comment under question

Comment: That was it thank you so much.

Comment: @KittyKat  glad to help you. please read my answer once again. I have added some note as well explanation too.